# Primefaces: disable ajaxStatus for datatable Filter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.5 and have a table in my xhtml. By clicking on a separate `commandButton`, i refresh the tabledata. Because of the amount of data i'm using the `ajaxStatus` to show a "Loading..." Dialog.

And now here's the problem: The table has to be filterable for each column. Everything works fine so far, but when i enter some filter criteria, the Loading-Dialog is also appearing.

**Is it possible to disable the `ajaxStatus` for the columns in my `dataTable`?** I tried the parameter `global="false"` but without any success. Best solution would be if it's possible to enable for just some components instead of disabling for some.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you'll benefit more from a targeted UI feedback component like [BlockUI](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml). Using that component, your blockUI will be triggered only by the command button and the datatable stays independent of that